# The right way to set up permissions for "workspaces" in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a site where users work together in "workspaces". A workspace is like an account for a group of users.

Each workspace will have a number of users. There are two user groups: "superusers" and "regular users".

A user may be a member of more than one workspace. The user can never belong to both user groups in the same workspace, but the user can be a "superuser" in one workspace and a "regular user" in another.

I am trying to find out whether I can create this type of setup using the out-of-the-box permissions framework in Django, or whether the best solution is to create my own supporting tables?

My own solution would be a data model like this:

```
#(assume default User model)

class Workspace(models.Model):
    workspace_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class WorkspaceUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    workspace = models.ForeignKey(Workspace)
    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=100) #for simplicity, would only have two options
```

Is this a sensible way to do it, or can I utilize the out-of-the-box framework to achieve the same instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the built-in permissions framework is just for the model level - ie "user can modify workspaces generally" rather than "user can modify this specific workspace".

Your solution looks sensible. One addition would be to add an explicit many-to-many declaration using the WorkspaceUser as the through table:

```
class Workspace(models.Model):
    workspace_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='WorkspaceUser')
```

This doesn't change the table structure but gives you the ability to do `my_user.workspace_set.all()` to get all workspaces for a user or `my_workspace.users.all()` to get all users for a workspace.

Comment: Much appreciated. Follow-up: When I use my_`user.workspace_set.all()` to get accounts for a user in views.py, how do I also get the usertype from WorkspaceUser "on my way" through the many-to-many-relation? Goal is to show one type of content to my "superusers" in my template and another to my "regular users". Do I use my accounts in a `request.user.account_set.all()` variable to create a dictionary of accounts and rights?

Comment: Yes those utility methods don't allow you to access the through table, you'd still have to go directly. Something like `request.user.workspaceuser_set.filter(workspace=my_workspace, usertype='super').exists()` or whatever.